# Authentification privacy API Key using client side AJAX request

Tags: ajax, authentication

I'm working on a small project with 0 budget. 
I have to build up the website and the Tumblr of a band. 
Actually the band is using Songkick to announce their Tour Dates. 
My goal is to embed Songkick data both in their website and Tumblr. 
So i look at the Songkick API, applied for an API key and everything is fine.
The Songkick widget do the tricks however i don't like the layout and would like to catch a small set of the JSON response. That's why i decided to build my own API Call request using AJAX.

Host for the band is a free host with limited PHP support and not much extension available. So i can't find another reliable way to use the API rather than JS and AJAX stufF.

The problem i'm facing is that songkick API is using an API key you must pass to the request URL in order to get authenticated.  Is there any way i can avoid to pass my api key in plain text so that anyone can use it ? I read some threads here about other API, some API use OAUTH, tokens, or whitelist but seems Songkick isn't.

Should i try to invest server-side on the band website and just call that data using AJAX on the tumblr theme ? Or is there anyway to sort it using just JS ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The API key is not used for security, rather is a way to identify who (or from what app) the request comes from, so it would be ok to embed it in your javascript file.

Comment: I got the idea but what if someone use it and doesn't respect website policy ?